# Why can't my JavaScript toHexString function work properly with Uint8Array?

Tags: javascript

This is my toHexString function:

```
function toHexString(bytes) {
    return bytes.map(function (byte) {
        return ("00" + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2)
    }).join('')
}
```

And this is what I have done in Chrome Console:

```
> var bitmapArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);

undefined

> toHexString(bitmapArray.subarray(0,3))

"2100"

> bitmapArray.subarray(0,3)

[33, 29, 31]

> toHexString([33,29,31])

"211d1f"
```

It seems that toHexString function cannot work properly. What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`map` method of typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/map) returns another typed array of the same type. This will cast your strings `"21"`, `"1d"`, `"1f"` to bytes, by interpreting them as decimal integers - which the latter two are not, so `NaN` becomes `0` and you end up with the `Uint8Array([21, 0, 0])`.

To fix this, use a normal `Array` that can contain strings:

```
toHexString(Array.from(bitmapArray.subarray(0,3)))
```

or probably even better

```
function toHexString(bytes) {
    return Array.from(bytes, byte =>
        ("00" + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2)
    ).join('');
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: How could I do that on elder browsers such as IE? It seems that IE doesn't support `Array.from`. Neither does Safari.

Comment: You can easily [polyfill `Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill), but I doubt older browsers would support typed arrays anyway (and certainly not typed arrays with a `map` method).